# Why should I set UITextField delegate to itself in init?

Tags: uitextfield, exc-bad-access, uitextfielddelegate

I have set first time my CustomUITextField delegate like this below. But I get a nasty exc-bad-access crash when editing text.

```
CustomTextField *textField = [[CustomTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 132, 44)];
textField.delegate = textField;
```

After that I put it to CustomTextField's init method and than it works.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Why are you setting the custom textField's delegate to an instance of itself and not the viewController? If you want the CustomTextField to have the same delegate methods as UITextField make the CustomTextField inherit from UITextField. If you want to extend the protocol, then define a protocol for the CustomTextField class and make it conform to the UITextField delegate. Then, re-declare the delegate property.

Comment: CustomTextField is inherited from UITextField